# ¿Alguien dice «octetos» en lugar de «bytes»?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, informática, neologismos

Alguien que conozco comparte esta imagen donde se utiliza la palabra *octeto* como traducción de *[byte](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6MofNvJ)*. Quien la comparte trabaja en informática pero no tenía idea de que los bytes (conjunto de ocho [bits](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5cPrUzM)) se llamasen también así. Yo he visto en alguna parte esta traducción pero daba por hecho que ya estaba obsoleta, y en cualquier caso, no creo haber escuchado a nadie jamás usarla. ¿Se usa *octeto* con este significado en alguna parte, en la práctica? ¿Se usó alguna vez fuera de las traducciones oficiales de Windows en algunos países, manuales de software, libros de texto, etc.?

[image: octetos]

Comment: Me gusta la palabra -- aunque me hace pensar en un ensamble de música de cámara....

Comment: Técnicamente, 'byte' es ambiguo: puede significar un *byte* [de cualquier cantidad de bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte), como se ha usado en el pasado (pero sí, su uso actual es casi siempre de una colección de ocho bits). Creo que se emplearía el sinónimo octeto en contextos (formales) donde es importante evitar la ambigüedad.

Comment: Está en el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qt1ESpr)

Comment: al igual que pilas y colas para Stack y Queue, aunque me pareceria sumamente tierno llamarle "pedacitos" a los bits xD

Comment: @Rodrigo En efecto está, pero curiosamente no está vinculada como sinónimo a *byte* ni viceversa.

Comment: @Mike "Ocho pedacitos forman un mordysco."

Comment: @pablodf76 en el DPD sí está vinculada como sinónimo a *byte*: "[**octeto.**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=octeto) → *[byte](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=f3Rl2iC0nD6clhAZV7).*" "Por tratarse de una unidad de medida de circulación internacional, se emplea normalmente como extranjerismo crudo, con su grafía y pronunciación originarias, aunque no debe olvidarse que el equivalente español de este anglicismo es *octeto*"

Comment: Cuando estaba involucrado en el mundo de las redes de computadoras, era bastante común referirse como octetos a alguna de las 4 posiciones que conforman una [dirección IP](https://support.microsoft.com/es-ec/help/164015/understanding-tcp-ip-addressing-and-subnetting-basics), por ejemplo, recuerdo que se decía "*-¿Cuál dijiste que era el tercer octeto de la IP de fulanito? -128*".

Comment: @pablodf efectivo inmediatamente queda desterrada la palabra byte de mi vocabulario para exclusivamente usar ***mordysco*** informático, definido como una colección de *n* pedacitos. Es la traducción más genial y oportuna que he encontrado ¡Me fascina!

Comment: He visto la palabra  *octet* en inglés.  No estoy seguro pero creo que solamente se usa cuando  *byte* sería ambigua.

Comment: For what it worth, in French *octet* is routinely used instead of *byte* giving *kilooctet*, *mégaoctet*, *gigaoctet* and so on. On the other hand, *bit* has no local translation so is used as is (*kilobits, mégabits*...)

Comment: Recuerdo en los años 1990 ver la palabra "octeto" en manuales de IBM traducidos para España; también en libro sobre temas de informática que fueron traducidos del francés al español para su venta en España. También en libros sobre telecomunicaciones.

Answer (score 3):

A veces se usa el concepto octeto en telecomunicaciones, para hacer referencia a datos cuyo contenido en bits es relevante y para enfatizar que son sólo ocho bits, sin bits para checksum o para otro tipo de control. Por eso es que muchas normas de protocolos hacen uso exhaustivo de la palabra octeto para hacer referencia al tamaño de un campo en un paquete de comunicación.
Nunca he visto que se use para representar almacenamiento.

Comment: En telecomunicaciones y en electrónica se utiliza habitualmente octeto para señales o grupos de señales de ocho bits.

Comment: De hecho me sorprende que no sea más común en castellano -haciendo referencia al unidades de almacenamiento- el uso de los prefijos  para denotar bytes (mordyscos? <3 ) binarios o decimales, v.gr: Mb = Megabyte =  1*10^3 Kb1*10^6 b mientras que Mib = **Mebibyte** = 2^10 **kibibytes** (Kib) = 2^20 bytes, luego KB < Kib y la diferencia son 24b

Answer (score 1):

Un byte es un grupo de dígitos binarios adyacentes tratados como una unidad y generalmente menor que una palabra de ordenador. Frecuentemente tiene el sentido de un grupo de ocho bits. Se recomienda el uso de **bit** para el *bit* y **b** para el *byte u octeto*, aunque en la práctica, es común encontrar **B** por *byte* y **b** por *bit*, lo cual es inaceptable en el SI porque **B** es el símbolo del *belio*.

El término fue acuñado por Werner Buchholz en 1956 durante la primera fase de diseño del ordenador Stretch de IBM. Originalmente estaba compuesto por seis bits. El paso a ocho bits ocurrió a finales de 1956, y pasó a ser una norma en el System/360.

**Las unidades de medida**

(Como referencia al [Sistema Internacional de Medidas en el NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/index.html), que ya lo siento pero no hay versión en español)

Conjunto de unidades coordinadas, determinadas por convenios internacionales (IEC), que permiten expresar la medida de cualquier magnitud física. El tamaño de las unidades viene expresado por el uso de prefijos, que en el Sistema Internacional de medidas (SI), son:

```
 yotta - Y  - 1.0e24  = 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
 zetta - Z  - 1.0e21  = 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 
 exa   - E  - 1.0e18  = 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 
 peta  - P  - 1.0e15  = 1 000 000 000 000 000 
 tera  - T  - 1.0e12  = 1 000 000 000 000 
 giga  - G  - 1.0e9   = 1 000 000 000 
 mega  - M  - 1.0e6   = 1 000 000 
 kilo  - k  - 1.0e3   = 1 000 
 hecto - h  - 1.0e2   = 100 
 deca  - da - 1.0e1   = 10 
 1 
 deci  - d  - 1.0e-1  = 0.1 
 centi - c  - 1.0e-2  = 0.01 
 milli - m  - 1.0e-3  = 0.001 
 micro - µ  - 1.0e-6  = 0.000 001 
 nano  - n  - 1.0e-9  = 0.000 000 001 
 pico  - p  - 1.0e-12 = 0.000 000 000 001 
 femto - f  - 1.0e-15 = 0.000 000 000 000 001 
 atto  - a  - 1.0e-18 = 0.000 000 000 000 000 001 
 zepto - z  - 1.0e-21 = 0.000 000 000 000 000 000 001 
 yocto - y  - 1.0e-24 = 0.000 000 000 000 000 000 000 001
```

En 1998 se creó un nuevo sistema de prefijos para denotar **múltiplos binarios** por la IEC. La norma introduce los prefijos **kibi, mebi, gibi, tebi, pebi y exbi**, nombres formados con la primera sílaba de cada prefijo del SI y el sufijo **bi** por binario. La norma también estipula que los prefijos SI siempre tendrán los valores de potencias de 10 y nunca deberán ser usados como potencias de 2.

```
 kibi - Ki - 2^10 = 1 024 
 mebi - Mi - 2^20 = 1 048 576 
 gibi - Gi - 2^30 = 1 073 741 824 
 tebi - Ti - 2^40 = 1 099 511 627 776 
 pebi - Pi - 2^50 = 1 125 899 906 842 624 
 exbi - Ei - 2^60 = 1 152 921 504 606 846 976
```

IEC = International Electrotechnical Commission

Comment: Interesante y documentada respuesta, como siempre. Lo que echo en falta es explicar lo que se pregunta: ¿se dice en algún lugar o contexto _octetos_ en lugar de _bytes_?

Comment: Cuando yo empecé en esto de la informática (1971) se empleaba **octeto**. Después paso a ser de uso común **byte**. Y como cada vez estamos más lejos del lenguaje máquina se suele hablar de **carácter** como mucho. Aunque con sistemas de codificación de doble byte, como el UNICODE, se hace un poco raro asimilar carácter con byte/octeto.

Comment: Ajá, esa es la información que creo que el autor de la pregunta quería saber específicamente. Y de hecho esto encaja con [la gráfica que nos muestra Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=octeto%2Cbyte&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cocteto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbyte%3B%2Cc0).